# Unable to retrieve value of static variable in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to access a static variable set in one Java class in another class. I am using the syntax properly I guess but I am getting null everytime.

Could someone help with this?

Class 1:

```
public class Test { 

    public static List<String> dbobj;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> accnos= new ArrayList<String>();

        accnos.add("1");
        accnos.add("2");
        accnos.add("3");
        dbobj=accnos;
        System.out.println("dbobj"+dbobj);
    }
}
```

Class 2 :

```
public class Test2 {

    public void main(String args[]) {

    List<String> list1= Test.dbobj;
    System.out.println("List value"+list1);  **//COMING AS NULL**
    }   
}
```

Comment: public static List<String> dbobj = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: use a static initializer block

Comment: `List<String> dbobj` is initialized in `Test.main` method. Before that method will be executed it holds its default value `null`.

Comment: You aren't calling Test.main(); Therefore, it isn't initialized.

Comment: If you launch those two classes as distinct applications, they run in distinct VMs and classes are not shared since they are loaded by distinct VMs

Answer (score 1):

You have two entry points (*programs*) which absolutely independent of each other.

When you are calling a `Test.dbobj`, the `main` method from the `Test` is not executed, therefore its initialisation `dbobj=accnos;` is not called.

It is *a bit* awkward, but you could call the `Test.main(args);` before printing to execute that init process.

Comment: dbobj[1, 2, 3]
List value[]

Comment: Output if i do Test.main(args) above it in class Test2

Comment: @SouravMehra, I have tested it, `dbobj[1, 2, 3]\nList value[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: No change in class 1 and class 2 looks like this

public class Test2 {

    public void main(String args[]) {
    Test.main(args);
    List<String> list1= Test.dbobj;
    System.out.println("List value"+list1);  
    }   
}

Answer (score 0):

When you're within the `main` method of `Test2`, the `main` of `Test` has not been called.
The static variable `dbobj` has therefore its initial value, being `null`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't have 2 main functions and expect it to run both, so the better way to do this would be using a static code block in Class1 like this

```
static {
    List<String> accnos= new ArrayList<String>();

    accnos.add("1");
    accnos.add("2");
    accnos.add("3");
    dbobj=accnos;
    System.out.println("dbobj"+dbobj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this changes in your class Test2:

```
Test.main(args); // added
List<String> list1= Test.dbobj;
```

Problem is you are using static variable `dbobj` from class `Test` without initializing that given variable. As of now, `dbobj` is assigned value inside `Test.main()`, so likewise you need to invoke that method.

Comment: I tried that and then output is
dbobj[1, 2, 3]
List value []

Answer (score 0):

There is no code executed that initialized the **dbobj** list, when your invoke `main` method in Test2 class.  Therefore it points to NULL.

The easiest fix is to initialize it right when it is declared :

```
public static List<String> dbobj list = new ArrayList<>() {
  { add("str1"); add("str2"); }
};
```

The **other** solution is to fix Test1 class as below:

```
public class Test {
  public static List<String> dbobj;

  public static void init() {
    List<String> accnos = new ArrayList<>();
    accnos.add("1");
    accnos.add("2");
    accnos.add("3");
    dbobj=accnos;
    System.out.println("dbobj"+dbobj);
  }
}

public class Test2 {

    public void main(String args[]) {
      Test.init();
      List<String> list1 = Test.dbobj;
      System.out.println("List first value" + list1[0]);  // should be OK
    }   
}
```